# Template+Dependent Name

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-bug

$14.6.2/3 - "In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template, if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member."

As per this, the call `'f(0)'` in `'D::g'` should call `'B:f'`. However gcc(IdeOne) gives an ambiguit error.

Is this a bug in gcc? Comeau compiles it fine

```
template<class T, class U> struct A{
   template<class A, class B> A f(B b){A a; return a;}
};

struct B{
   double f(double d){return 0.0;}
};

template<class T, class U> struct D : A<T, U>, B{
   void g(){f(0);}
};

int main(){
   D<double, double> d;
   d.g();
}
```

Comment: VS 2008 also gives the ambiguity error.

Comment: I think GCC finds the `f` in `B` and adds the implicit class member access prematurely, `this->f(0)`, which makes GCC to look up in `A<T,U>` at instantiation. This is the wrong way - see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5838

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is a [known GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24163) which has been fixed.

According to the bug report, your example fails as late as GCC 4.4.0.  I think that just means it hasn't been tested on a newer version though - not that it's been fixed.

Comment: Vow!. Thanks for the reference