# Template programming - Common Mistakes

Tags: c++, templates, wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ template gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877687/c-template-gotchas)

Hi,

I am just in to my second month on SO, and I have seen enough number of posts on SO related to several common issues with templates. Is it a good idea to make a small Wiki on this (sadly I don't know how to make one)?

The idea is to provide a reference as definitive as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (GMan's favourite)

Here is the first one from me

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

If there already exists one or if this idea is not appealing, please feel free to vote it for closure. I will also vote for it :)

Comment: may be duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877687/c-template-gotchas

Comment: You make one just by checking the "Community Wiki" box when asking the question.  You should also have that option when editing your own question.

Comment: I'd think that resources like this should be collected on [the `templates` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/templates/info).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks, I did not notice that.

Comment: @James McNellis: Oh!. Have voted for closure. Let's add it on the templates tag wiki as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

### A quick summary of typename

The `typename` keyword has two meanings in C++. `typename` can be used as a substitute for `class` in template parameter lists.

```
// These two lines mean exactly the same thing.
template<typename A> class Foo {};
template<class A> class Foo {};
```

The other reason is more complicated. `typename` tells a compiler that a dependent name is in fact a type.

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef T MyType; // Okay.
    typedef T::Type OtherType; // Wrong.
};
```

This is wrong because the compiler thinks that `T::Type` is not in fact a type, so the `typedef` fails. `T` might define `Type` as something that's not a type (like a static member), so the compiler must default to treating `T::Type` as a non-type since it doesn't know what `T` is until it is instantiated. In this situation, `T::Type` is what standardese calls a *dependent name*. Note that `T` is a *non-dependent name* because the compiler knows that `T` is in fact a type (it's one of the template type parameters), so that doesn't require `typename`.

In this case, you must give a hint to the compiler:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef T MyType; // Okay.
    typedef typename T::Type OtherType; // Okay.
};
```

Unfortunately, due to compiler bugs, a compiler may compile the snippet without `typename` without errors, even though it is not legal!

Answer (score 1):

some fun stuff with deduced template types.

compilers treat the following cases differently.

```
struct F {
    typedef int value_type;
};

struct B : F {
    B::value_type value;          // some compilers, edg
    typename B::value_type value;  // other compilers, gcc
    BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME B::value_type value;  // Boost!!!
};
```

to make this crazy, nvcc cuda compiler is actually two compilers, edg and gcc, rolled into one which both process the same file.  however, typename deduction is different for both of them, so it makes BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME unsuitable. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Dependent bases are never searched during [unqualified name lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684756/templatedependent-name)

```
struct base{
    virtual void f(){}
};

template<class T> struct anotherbase{
    virtual void f(){}
};

template<class T> struct derived : base, anotherbase<T>{
    void g(){f();}
};

int main(){
    derived<int> d;
    d.g();             // not ambiguous. should call base::f
                        // unqualified name 'f' is not looked up 
                        // anotherbase<int>
}
```